# Is it possible to check if a list is empty OOTB in SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I have a SharePoint vouchers list, during the workflow a user requests a voucher, if it is approved the voucher is moved to a different list to keep as a record and deleted from the initial list.
However when the voucher list is empty it is throwing an error.

I want to be able to check if the list is empty before the workflow tries to send the voucher and delete it from the list, so I can handle the situation.

Is it posisble to do this out of the box in SharePoint designer as my manager wants to avoid code on the server if at all possible.

Comment: Are you using SharePoint 2013 Designer Workflows or SharePoint 2010 Designer Workflow ?

Comment: 2010, If absoutely necessary I could probably redesign the WF again in 2013 if it would solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned that **SharePoint 2013 Designer Workflows** are a viable option , you can use the new SharePoint 2013 "**Call an HTTP Web Service**" action in your designer workflow, this ways you can do REST actions and get count of items. Here is an example for doing a similair [task](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/looping-through-list-items-in-sharepoint-2013) .

Also here is the relavent webservice to get the item count

```html
https://www.siteurl.com/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('ListName')/itemcount
```

Comment: ok thanks I will give that a go. Just to clarify, checking if a list is empty is only available OOTB in SP 2013 ?

Comment: OOTB in SharePoint Designer Workflow to be specific.